# Restructuring an array javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary

I'm working with OpenLayers 3 and am making popups.  I would like to organize the array I get from a sql view into an order by creating child arrays.  I've been looking into trees and the $.map function, but I am still not able to properly organize the data since the parent/child relationships from the database are lost in a view.

This is an example of data (Please note that this is dynamic; the array will be different with each request):

```
var list = [
{samplename: "samp1", chemicalname: "foo1", result: 16, qualifier: "X"},
{samplename: "samp1", chemicalname: "foo", result: 10, qualifier: "X"},
{samplename: "samp1", chemicalname: "foo1", result: 109, qualifier: "X"},
{samplename: "samp1", chemicalname: "foo", result: 418, qualifier: "A"},
{samplename: "samp2", chemicalname: "foo1", result: 411, qualifier: "AU"},
{samplename: "samp2", chemicalname: "foo", result: 4, qualifier: "Z"},
{samplename: "samp2", chemicalname: "foo1", result: 1, qualifier: "XY"},
{samplename: "samp3", chemicalname: "foo1", result: 100, qualifier: "X"},
{samplename: "samp3", chemicalname: "foo", result: 140, qualifier: "AX"}
{samplename: "samp4", chemicalname: "foo", result: 1478, qualifier: "XA"}
];
```

This is what I have so far:

```
          pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
          map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature, layer) {   
            var featureprops = feature.getProperties();  
          var array = $.map(featureprops, function(value, index) {
return {name:index, value:value};
});
console.log(array);

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'group', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function (key) {
    var map = {};
    this.forEach(function (e) {
        if(e.name=='chemical_name') {
      var k = key(e);
      map[k] = map[k] || [];
      map[k].push(e);
  }
  if(e.name=='result_numeric') {
       var k = key(e);
       map[k] = map[k] || [];
       map[k].push(e);
   }
    if(e.name=='lab_qualifiers') {
       var k = key(e);
       map[k] = map[k] || [];
       map[k].push(e);
   }
     });
     return Object.keys(map).map(function (k) {
       return {key: k, data: map[k]};
     });
   }
 });

 var newArray = array.group(function (item) {   
   return item.chemical_name;
 });
 console.log(newArray);
 //other code follows
```

Is there a more efficient way to build this?  Also, this function now is only returning the properties for the first feature.  I need the array to be built for each sample and grouped by each unique sample.

The output I would want would be something like

```
{  
name: 'samp1', 
results: [{
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo1
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 16
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'X'
      },{
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 10
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'X'
      },{
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo1
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 109
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'X'
      },{
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 418
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'A'
      }],
name: 'samp2', 
results: [{          
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo1
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 411
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'AU'
      },{
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 4
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'Z'
      },{
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo1
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 1
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'XY'
      }
}],
 name: 'samp3', 
results: [{          
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo1
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 100
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'X'
      },{
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: foo
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 140
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'AX'
      }],
name: 'samp4', 
results: [{  
        key:'chemicalname', 
        value: 'foo'
    },{
        key: 'result',
        value: 1478
    },{
        key: 'qualifier',
        value: 'XA'
      }]
}
```

Comment: Please include the expected output

Comment: `This is an example of data:` - how about an example of the data as it is in code ... you say it's an Array, but what you've shown is not an Array

Comment: Can you show us your starting data and what you want, in a form that would be valid on the right hand side of an assignment.

Comment: The data is dynamic and pulled from a server through Geoserver however I will make up some dummy data

Comment: Example is updated, apologies (i'm still learning :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I ended up using:

```
   var features = [];
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
      features.push(feature);
    });
    var samples = [];
for (var i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; i++) {samples.push({sample_name:features[i].get('sample_name'),sample_date:features[i].get('sample_date'),start_depth:features[i].get('start_depth'),end_depth:features[i].get('end_depth'),chemical_name:features[i].get('chemical_name'),result_numeric:features[i].get('result_numeric'),lab_qualifiers:features[i].get('lab_qualifiers')});
};

Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
  return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
var val = item[prop];
groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
groups[val].push(item);
return groups;
}, {});
}

var data = samples.groupBy('sample_name');
console.log(data);
```

The next task is converting the object into an HTML table, however that is beyond the scope of this question.